# Flask: Cannot Deploy App to Heroku, No Module named 'app'

Tags: python, flask, heroku

I'm trying to deploy my app to Heroku. My folder structure is this:

[image]

All my code is written inside `__init__.py`, and I run this by just typing `flask run` while in the root directory. This works fine. However, I tried deploying this app to Heroku and I got the following error:

```
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed: cannot parse Procfile.
remote:  !     Please try pushing again.
remote:  !     If the problem persists, see https://help.heroku.com/ and provide Request ID 266c0fb8-18bd-a262-5d3a-4355cd83bb02.
remote:
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to submission-form.
remote:
```

My `Procfile` contains this: `web: gunicorn app:app` and my `app.py` contains this:

```
from app import app
app.run(debug=True)
```

If I try running `python app.py`, my modules are reported missing:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 1, in <module>
    from app.app import app
  File "D:\Gatsby\submission\flask-tailwindcss-starter\app\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from contentful_management import Client
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'contentful_management'
```

This is despite them being there and running perfectly when I use `flask run`. What is going wrong here? How do I fix this so I can push this app to deploy on Heroku? I'm guessing this has something to do with my `procfile`.

Edit: [My repo is attached here, if it helps](https://github.com/thedivtagguy/submission)

Comment: I don't see any app in your git repo, can you again push the code to github so that I can try it on my machine

Comment: @charchit, Hi! Sorry about that. I just pushed a commit again, it is now in the repo.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling app from app.app module. First there is no module app.app and there is no app defined.
try this :

```
from app import create_app
app = create_app()
app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: I'm still getting a `Push failed: cannot parse Procfile.` error. I've changed my `app.py` to what you said. The procfile contents are `web: gunicorn app:app`. Is my `app.py` placed correctly in the directory structure? It's currently in the root directory.

Comment: I will push this to my heroku , is there a way I can contact you, like discord or anything else. because this can be too long.

Comment: Honestly, that would be amazing. I've been trying to make this one script work for a week and I would like any guidance I can get. My username is thedivtagguy#0167